# Cannot set property 'functionName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning MEVN by watching this video https://youtu.be/H6hM_5ilhqw?t=38m28s

And I imitated to add a function to const User like below:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Datatypes) =>{
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email:{
      type:Datatypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    password:Datatypes.STRING
  }, {
    hooks:{
      beforeCreate: hashPassword,
      beforeUpdate: hashPassword,
      beforeSave: hashPassword
    }
  })

  User.prototype.comparePassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, this.password)
  } 

  return User
}
```

But it always shows that `TypeError: Cannot set property 'comparePassword' of undefined`

(The tutorial video has no problem with it.)

[image: here is the error]

I have tried to use "User.____proto____.comparePassword", and it was compiled successfully but cannot pass the function to its instance.

Hope someone can help me out, thanks!

Comment: `User` object is not defined

Comment: `User` is not an object...

Comment: Please do not use pictures of text... both are able to be copy, pasted, and formatted within the editor. Pictures make it harder to copy code in question for testing purposes.

Comment: Okay I edit it now

Comment: Which version of sequelize are you using? Are you sure you use the 4.x? You could possibly be using an older version which doesn't support this way of extending instances.

Comment: "sequelize": "^3.33.0"

Comment: This is it. Upgrade to 4.X. Older versions have different way of extending instances.

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes

Comment: @WiktorZychla Ohh...So it could be returned with an object in v3 but a function in v4 ?

Comment: @WiktorZychla  Thank you very much and I know how to fix it!

Comment: Yes, I've posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an older version of sequelize that doesn't yet support extending instances by using prototypes.

According to [their documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes) the older way would be to provide `instanceMethods`

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {...}
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        someMethod: function () { ...}
    }
});
```

The 4.X works like you tried to make it to work.